# argument "no" is missing, with no default ifelse

Tags: r

I want to create another binary variable `y` condition on different categories of the variable `x`.

if the variable `x` is "a" or "b" or "c" I want `y` to be equal to 1, if `x` is "d" or "e" `y=0`

My code is as follows

```
data$y <- ifelse(data$x == "a" | data$x == "b" |data$x == "c", 1, 
ifelse(data$x == "d" | data$loan_status == "e" ,0))
```

I am receiving an error :

> argument "no" is missing, with no default"

I have checked other similar questions but that does not solve my problem.

Comment: It's asking for value when `data$x == "d" | data$loan_status == "e"` is `FALSE`

Comment: the question `argument “no” is missing, with no default` already exists, that's why you had to mispell yours, and it contains your answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ifelse` requires 3 arguments, the first is called `test`, the second is called `yes`, the third is called `no`.

Your inner `ifelse` statement only has two arguments, which is not enough:

```
ifelse(data$x == "d" | data$loan_status == "e", 0)
```

Hence the third argument, `no`, is missing. I would recommend setting it to something like `NA`, that way anything that does not meet either of your conditions will be set to the missing value `NA`.

As a side note, the `%in%` function is a lot nicer to use than lots of ORs. I would rewrite your code one of two ways:

```
# this is nice and simple if you are sure data$x only takes values
# a,b,c,d,e
ifelse(data$x %in% c("a", "b", "c"), 1, 0)

# this is good if there is even a tiny chance data$x has other values
# it will flag the other values as NA
ifelse(data$x %in% c("a", "b", "c"), 1, ifelse(data$x %in% c("c", "d"), 0, NA))
```